# Mobile Development for iPhone, Android, and Blackberry

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, cordova

I recently stumbled into PhoneGap and I love the concept, but I can't get my first try at an  Android application working.  The documentation skips a few details and the comments are filled with people running into problems.

Does anyone out there have PhoneGap running?  What did you tweak for Android?

Comment: Did you try asking on the PhoneGap Google Group? The answers are usually pretty quick there.

Comment: Thanks for steering me toward PhoneGap.  It is exactly what I was looking for.  Have you built any apps using PhoneGap?

Comment: I am tied into the google group now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are about 3 different frameworks, PhoneGap, QuickConnect, and  Rhomobile.

QuickConnect and Rhomobile have better documents at least for Android support.

I used PhoneGap for a little bit then switched to QuickConnect and Rhomobile.

Comment: I found an overview of Javascript iphone languages. 

http://ejohn.org/blog/iphone-javascript-apps/


Anyone have preferences on these?

Answer (score 0):

how i setup phonegap was,
boot with Linux liveCD, go to the folder of phonegap, and run the makefile. it will generate javascript files. copy the phonegap.js to the assets, boot with windows again and include the phonegap javascript file in your main html.