# What options are there for cross-platform (iPhone, Android, Blackberry) development?

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, cross-platform

Me and my friends are starting app development. We have created 2 apps now, and have 3 more in the works. We're looking for a development tool or environment that will allow us to build games that works on all the major handsets. We're using Flash at the moment for cross-platform, but are there any better and more powerful options?

Or would it be best to write the code in one language, then convert it line by line to the others? How do the creators of games like Angry Birds do it?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937724/mobile-development-for-iphone-android-and-blackberry

Comment: possible duplicate of [What work has been done on cross-platform mobile development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988/what-work-has-been-done-on-cross-platform-mobile-development)

Answer (score 2):

There are many options:

- PhoneGap
- SAP Sybase Unwired Platform
- Appcelerator Titanium
- RhoMobile
- Kony

Out of all these mentioned tools i will recommend PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1):

Also [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) and [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/)

Comment: PhoneGap with Sencha or JQuery Mobile is decent

Answer (score 0):

My friends are using [this](http://www.appcelerator.com/) for making games , and am a designer so not much into programming of that. But still as far my friends say this is good for most of the applications, though there are very few things which cant be implemented.

My friends have created a utility app and a game tic tac to using this.

Answer (score 0):

For developing games i would recommend **Corona**.

For a native feel and look i would recommend **Titanium**

For fast and simple development and using html/js i would recommend **Phonegap**

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out Worklight from IBM.  You can easily download the fully functional development tool from their developerworks Web site.  The only restriction is that you can't use what you write for a production version.  Their tutorials are great and escort you comfortably through the short learning curve.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a Titanium Developer, I find this framework great because it gives me the chance to develop cross browser mobile with Javascript. This is a big advantage for people that have Web Developing background like me. If you are gonna develop basic cross browser application und you will do it quick (and if you have javascript know-how), then appcelerator is good for you!